# Is every linear transformation with at least two eigenvalues decomposable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

(A linear transformation $T : V \rightarrow V$ is decomposable if $V$ can be written as the direct sum of two proper $T$-invariant subspaces)

Some background for this question: I have been going back over linear algebra recently, with the intention of pushing standard theorems and proofs to their bare essentials, so I can get an idea of when a property is "necessary" and when it is only "sufficient".

For example the theorem which states "Every finite-dimensional inner product space $V$ induces a natural isomorphism $V \rightarrow V^*$, given by $v \mapsto <v,->$" has nothing to do with symmetry or the full power of positive definiteness. So this can be generalised from an inner product to a non-degenerate bilinear form. However this theorem **does** depend on the finite dimensionality of $V$, and so any proof must make use of this property.

Now I have been trying to prove the following theorem (or find a counter example to it). "Given that $V$ is a vector space, and $T : V \rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation with at least two distinct eigenvalues. Then $T$ is decomposable".

This theorem can be proven for the finite dimensional case by considering the Frobenius normal form of some matrix of $T$, but this proof explicitly uses the property of finite dimensionality. I have tried hard to produce either a more general proof that doesn't use finiteness, or a counter example in the infinite case, but I feel like I have hit a brick wall.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, so thank you in advance.

Comment: Let $x$ be an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $r\neq0$. Then the space generated by $(x)$ is $T$-invariant. We must have $(x)\neq M$, since $T$ has at least another eigenvalue other than the one for $x$. Let $v_i$, $i\in I$ be a basis of $M$ such that $v_0=x$. Take $w_i=v_i-x(v_i)x$, where $x(v_i)$ is the $x$-coordinate of $T(v_i)$ in the basis $v_i$. Then $x$ together with the $w_i$, for $i\in  I\setminus\{0\}$ is a basis of $M$ such that $N=(w_i,\ i\in I\setminus \{0\})$ is $T$-invariant and $(x)$ is $T$-invariant. Therefore $M=(x)\oplus N$ and $T$ is decomposable.

Comment: All is needed is one eigenvector with eigenvalue $\neq 0$ and dimension larger than $1$.

Comment: It is just column-reduction of the matrix of $T$. One of the first things one studies in linear algebra. Without choice you don't even know if an infinite dimensional $M$ (now I noticed that your name for the space was $V$) decomposes into a direct sum, let alone $T$-invariant subspaces. Focus more in understanding the very basics of linear algebra like Gauss elimination, before you start worrying about choice.

Comment: I have gone over your proof and realised the reason I never came up with it is because it is incorrect. Take the function $T : R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ given by $T(x,y) = (x+y,y)$. Then following your proof gives you $w_i = 0$ and it is not a basis. Also I do already know about Guassian elimination, and that it is not applicable here.

Comment: You don't know how to do Gaussian elimination, which it is perfetly applicable here. Try again.

Comment: The example I gave you is an obvious counter example to your proof because it has non-diagonal Jordan normal form of dimension two.

Comment: Let me be explicit. Take $T$ as I gave it, and then $x = (1,0)$ is a $1$-eigenvector of $T$. Then extend this to a basis where $v_2 = (0,1)$. Then $w_2 = v_2 - x(T(v_2)) x = (0,1) - x(1,1) (1,0) = (0,1) - (1,0) = (-1,1)$. Then $T(w_2) = (0,1)$, so Span($w_2$) is clearly not $T$-invariant.

Comment: @Sam Forster , your post is unclear. 1) Are your eigenvalues in $K$ (the underlying field) or in its algebraic closure? 2) Do you consider an infinite dimension vector space (then I have no time to look at) or a finite dimension one ? 3) Anyway, the  geometryfan's proof in its first comment is false even in finite dimension...4) I don't see how you can conclude using only the Frobenius normal form.

Comment: @loup blanc Hello, yes I am considering the infinite dimensional case as I am trying to work out if a proof **needs** finiteness or not. However yes I am saying the eigenvalues are in $K$, but I probably shouldn't have said **just** using Frobenius normal form - rather the proof I came up with uses it. (There is of course a simpler proof if $K$ is algebraically closed using Jordan form, but I wanted the more general case).

Comment: If there  are at least $2$ eigenvalues in $K$, then the required result is true and, to do that, the Jordan form is absolutely useless (in finite dimension).

Comment: I know the result is true in finite dimensions, but I don't think my proof is as nice as it could be. Do you mind sharing your proof (for the finite case)?

Answer (score 1):

We assume that i) or ii) is true

i) $V$ has finite dimension and $T$ has at least $2$ distinct eigenvalues in $K$.

ii) $V$ has infinite dimension and (*) there is $P(x)=(x-a)^r(x-b)^sQ(x)\in K[x]$ s.t. $a,b\in K,P(T)=0,Q(a)\not= 0,Q(b)\not= 0$ and $T$ does not cancel a strict divisor of $P$.

Then $V$ is $T$-decomposable.

Proof. For i), the condition (*) is also satisfied. The polynomials $(x-a)^r,(x-b)^s,Q(x)$ are pairwise prime; then

$V=\ker((T-aI)^r)\oplus[\ker((T-bI)^s)\oplus \ker(Q(T))]$ and we are done.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer as it is slicker than what I had. I am not going to tick it, just as I am still hoping to find an answer to my original question. Thank you very much :)